# Set OnClick attribute of an input with TR data-key and TD cell value when select a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

i am driving nuts on this.

I have a table and assign a class (`selected`) when I select the row.

Now, I have an input within a form and this is suppose to redirect to another page when OnClick, also it should parse 2 variables.

This 2 variables I take from the row selected.

`GetID` is the TD data-key attribute and `GetName` is the second column cell value.

My OnClick should look like this:

```
onclick="location.href='test.phtml?GetID=1&GetName=Name1'"
```

My Intention is:

Click on table row, assign class 'selected' and put data-key attribute of the TR element which has the class 'selected' (as value1) and the TD cell value (as value2) in my OnClick string.

The click thing works, but i cant get the string to work.

I have a fiddle here: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/765bmr7r/1/)

Comment: your onclick is not updating to "test.phtml?GetID=1&GetName=Name1" correct ?

Comment: yes, correct. It did not capture the TR data-key attribute and not the second cellvalue, also it is not building this OnClick string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check this approch :

https://jsfiddle.net/Kanzari/3sw01c9r/5/

it's a customized fork of your original code, base changes :

```
    $("#myTable tr").click(function(AddGroupIDandName) {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass("selected");
    $('.mybtn').attr('OnClick','./mysite.html?GetID='+$(this).attr('data-key')+'&GetName='+$(this).find('td:last-child').text());
});
```

Comment: I had to add location.href and put some extra single quotes before and after the location to make it work, this looks good anyway :) thanks. My code now: $('.mybtn').attr('OnClick','location.href='+"'"+'./mysite.html? GetID ='+$(this).attr('data-key')+'& GetName ='+$(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text()+"'");

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the following lines in your **$("#myTable tbody tr").on('click'**

```
var str = "location.href='test.phtml?GetID='" + $(this).data('key') +
            "'&GetName='" + $(this).find('td:last').text();
$(':input[value="Next"]').attr('onclickLocation', str);
```

```js
$('#myTable').on('click', '.selected', function(event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('bg-info')) {
        $(this).removeClass('bg-info');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('bg-info').siblings().removeClass('bg-info');
    }
});

$("#myTable tbody tr").on('click', function(AddGroupIDandName) {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass("selected");
    var str = "location.href='test.phtml?GetID='" + $(this).data('key') + "'&GetName='" + $(this).find('td:last').text();
    $(':input[value="Next"]').attr('onclickLocation', str);
    console.log('onclick is: ' + str);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-sm table-hover" id="myTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="selected" data-key="1">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Name1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="selected" data-key="2">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Name2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="selected" data-key="3">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Name3</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <form><input class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" onclick="location.href='test.phtml?GetID=1&GetName=Name1'" type="button" value="Next" ></form>
</div>
```